# How to execute two PDO statements in one function and prioritize which to execute first?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it a good practice to execute two statements in one function in PDO?
And if it is possible, how to add priority which statement to be executed?

Example  code:

```
function example() {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('Update blah blah');
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt1 = $db->prepare('Select blah blah');
    $stmt1->execute();
}
```

Comment: First statement will be executed first

Comment: Good practice? Perhaps - depends entirely on what you're doing. As for priority, it will happen in the sequence it's coded, first operation before the second operation. If you want to deviate from that order, you need to use some sort of qualifier in the function-call.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i'm just showing you the main issuenot the whole codes which is not necessary

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie thanks for the explanations buddy that's why i'm asking because for a second thought i think its not a good practice even tho its working

Comment: @u_mulder no i think not, because i tried to insert some data in first statement and Select in the second statement. but my second statement is giving some error that the data is not available. i think both statement executed same time

Comment: And I think you have __error__ in your first query and it doesn't run. And no data inserted, that's why second query finds nothing.

Comment: Nothing in PHP is executed "same time".

Comment: @Arnoldwannabe do you want to, perhaps, improve this question to add a bit more context/logic so that we can understand why you want a function to have sortable queries?  This question appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can call multiple statement in single function but this is not the best Practice.

you can call your  both queries like following way.

```
public function dbManager($order = 1)
{
    if($order == 1) 
    {
        $this->firstExample();
        $this->secondExample();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->secondExample();
        $this->firstExample();
    }

}

public function firstExample()
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('Update blah blah');
    $stmt->execute();
}


public function secondExample()
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('Update blah blah');
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

you can change the sequence by passing argument, if nothing passed it will work in default order.

Better to create once class and call methods based on your require order.